# Get collection of relation of Laravel Eloquent Collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have Article and Category models. A Category can have many Article. I select all active Article with as below:

```
 $list = Article::with('category')->whereActive('Y')->get();
```

Is there anyway to get all Category models in $list collection? Thanks for supporting.
PS: I am using Laravel 8.36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck) to get the categories list:

```
$list = Article::with('category')->whereActive('Y')->get();
$categories=$list->pluck('category');
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. It returns an array with null values. Pluck function will return the field category but there is no category field in Article model.

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake. You're answer is right absolutely.